# how to use retrofit with wordpress json api

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit2

i tried retrofit with simple json response which have `[ {},{},{},{},{},{},]` array of objects which works  but when i tried retrofit with status:

`{"ok",count: 4,count_total: 4,pages: 1,posts: [{},{},{},{}]   }`

I came up with null results ..plz find the correct solution how do i Call the retrofit for correct result.

**pojo class**`

```
public class Categories {
   @SerializedName("status")
  private int status;
    @SerializedName("id")
   private int id;
  @SerializedName("type")
  private String type;
 @SerializedName("title")
  private  String title;
  @SerializedName("content")
  private String content;

 public int getId() {
    return id;
}

 public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
}
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.movies_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ApiInterface apiService =
            ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<List<Categories>> call = apiService.response();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Categories>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Categories>> call, Response<List<Categories>> response) {

            List<Categories> movies = response.body();
            recyclerView
                    .setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies,
                            R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Categories>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

**apiclient.java**

```
public class ApiClient {

  public static final String BASE_URL = "http://androidaura.com/health/api/get_recent_posts/";
  private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


  public static Retrofit getClient() {
     if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `POJO` to following:

```
Public class Model {

      String status; // because "ok" is string not boolean
      int count;
      int count_total;
      int pages;
      List<Post> posts;


      public class Post {

        // add attribute of your old pojo 

      }
}
```

Also make sure your class attribute be same as Server response;

Comment: i m already doing this still getting nulll refernce error i have created a seprated class for response which have list of posts nd calling  a getposts method out of it

Comment: @rahul printStackTrace in your onFailure method to see what's is error.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List info.retrofit.model.PostResponse.getPostsList()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at info.retrofit.activity.MainActivity$1.onResponse

Comment: public void setPostsList(List<Posts> postsList) {
        this.postsList = postsList;
    }

Comment: Are you sure server return List<Posts> ?

Comment: add Interceptor to your Retrofit to see what's return by Webservice it will be very helpful.